# Значение предлога в

Tags: стилистика, стилистическая-ошибка

На одном из форумов по русскому языку задали такой вопрос.

В языках мира наблюдается следующая закономерность: чем короче слово, тем оно многозначнее. Это довольно логично: короткие слова можно быстро проговорить или написать, поэтому они используютсядостаточно часто. Например, предлоги в русском языке могут передавать огромное количество значений. ***Выберите все варианты, в которых предлог употреблен не в том же значении, что в примере .***   Девочка в джинсах.  Дырка в джинсах, Кот в сапогах, ключ в джинсах.

По смыслу только подходит "дырка в джинсах". Хотел дать ответ, но засомневался. Поскольку надо выбрать варианты.

Может, задание некорректное или я чего-то не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Принципиальная разница** между вариантами следующая:

а) девочка в джинсах,  Кот в сапогах,  ключ в джинсах;  б) дырка в джинсах.

В трех первых вариантах предмет (девочка, Кот, ключ) существует отдельно от джинсов, в то время как дырка относится к джинсам.

2) Если рассматривать **более частные значения**, то Кот в сапогах и девочка в джинсах —  одно и то же, а ключ в джинсах — это нечто другое.

Девочка в джинсах (то есть одетая в джинсы) —  здесь переносное значение. Прямое же значение заключается в том, что она как бы "частично находится внутри джинсов",  в то время как ключ целиком располагается в джинсах (лежит в кармане).

Comment: Я тоже все эти варианты учел. Я исходил из первого значения предлога в  в словаре Кузнецова.  ком-чём Указывает на место, пространство, вместилище, среду, сферу деятельности и т.п. в пределах или внутри которых находится кто-, что-л., происходит что-л.

Comment: А какое значение подобрать для предлога "в" в словосочетаниях: дырка в джинсах, ключ в джинсах?

Comment: Девочка в джинсах: 1) одета; 2) завернута. Кот в сапогах: 1) обут; 2) спит среди обуви. Ключ в джинсах: 1) в кармане; 2) завернут.

Comment: Серж,  дырка в джинсовой материи - дырка в джинсах; ключ в кармане джинсов - ключ в джинсах. Здесь перенос по смежности.

Answer (score 1):

Не подходят два варианта: *дырка в джинсах* и *ключ в джинсах*.

Если в ответе нужно выбрать все варианты, то выбор одного варианта также является возможным ответом. То есть ни о какой некорректности задания в этом отношении речь идти не может.